# Re-sorting array via array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays, `$country` and `$redirect` with each entry corresponding with it's exact counterpart e.g. `$redirect[1]` and `$country[1]`.

After un-setting values throughout the array, I might be left with, for example, an array where only `$var[4]` and `$var[2]` are set. I want to re-assign array keys from 0 upwards, so that `$var[2]` would have it's key re-assigned to `$var[0]` and `$var[4]` re-assigned to `$var[1]`.

Essentially the `sort()` function, but sorting by current array key, as oppose to the numeric/string value of an array.

Is this possible?

Any answers or advice would be greatly appreciated ;)!

**UPDATE:**

I've attempted to use both `ksort()` and `array_values()`, however I'm not sure they're really what I need, as I plan on using the `size_of()` function.

My code:

```
$var = array(2 => "value_1", 4 => "value_2", 6 => "value_3");
ksort($var);
for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($var); $i < $size; $i++) {
    $var[$i] = "foo";
}
var_dump($var);
```

Returns:

```
array(5) { [2]=> string(3) "foo" [4]=> string(7) "value_2" [6]=> string(7) "value_3" [0]=> string(3) "foo" [1]=> string(3) "foo" }
```

Any additional ideas/answers on how I could get this to work would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) (returns "sorted" array):

```
$var = array(2 => "value_1", 4 => "value_2", 6 => "value_3");
$var = array_values($var);
for($i = 0, $size = sizeof($var); $i < $size; $i++) {
    $var[$i] = "foo";
}
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: Huge thanks, I'll accept your answer when the timer drops ;)!

Comment: Oh, is there any reason to use `array_values() `over `ksort()`?

Comment: No. `ksort()` will work the best in your case as it works in-place.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for, as it doesn't seem to re-sort the array, at least in this example (http://pastebin.com/xWEuK48j). The reason I need it, is so that I can use the `sizeof()` function in conjunction with a `for()` loop, as demonstrated in that example. Any idea of what I could do?

Comment: Edited answer. You need `array_values()`.